# Error when trying to insert date into datetime column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a form that is trying to insert some data into an SQL Server 2008 database. The form has a function to get the current date/time and then insert it into the database as follows;

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." ( username, password, userid, userlevel, email, created, updated, timestamp, fullname, avatar )
VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '0', $ulevel, '$email', '$now', '$now', $time, '$fullname', $avatar)";
```

However, when the form submits it reports an error of;

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'created', table 'dbo.users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

We have done an echo $q to show the data trying to be inserted and it does show the correct datetime (e.g. 2009-10-28 15:43:00.000), the .000 gets added by the db normally.

If I manually create a record in the database, the datetime in the example above is accepted.

Wondered if anyone had come across this issue before?

Thank you.
Neil

Comment: For heaven's sake, us parameterized queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of '$now' like so:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." ( username, password, userid, userlevel, email, created, updated,   timestamp, fullname, avatar )
VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '0', $ulevel, '$email', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $time, '$fullname', $avatar)";
```

Comment: Thanks man, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP works perfectly. It's weird how it worked when we were using a different sql server (albeit using the same version and the exact same database).

Answer (score 1):

```
Try NOW() if you are trying to add current timestamp.

    $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." ( username, password, userid, userlevel, 
email, created, updated, timestamp, fullname, avatar )
    VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '0', $ulevel, 
'$email', NOW(), NOW(), $time, '$fullname', $avatar)";
```

UPDATE

oh its sql server

probably you'd use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP then

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME()
    ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    ,SYSUTCDATETIME()
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ,GETDATE()
    ,GETUTCDATE();
/* Returned:
SYSDATETIME()      2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381 -07:00
SYSUTCDATETIME()   2007-04-30 20:10:02.0474381
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  2007-04-30 13:10:02.047
GETDATE()          2007-04-30 13:10:02.047
GETUTCDATE()       2007-04-30 20:10:02.047
```

you can see that current_timestamp gives back date alongwith time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, possible this solution will be helpful: check that you have a `yyyy-DD-mm` date format (not `yyyy-mm-DD`), because by default, mssql accept date in `yyyy-DD-mm` format.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL Server has GETDATE() function for current datetime, so try:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." ( username, password, userid, userlevel, email, created, updated, timestamp, fullname, avatar )
VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '0', $ulevel, '$email', GETDATE(), GETDATE(), $time, '$fullname', $avatar)";
```