# Error when trying to insert date into datetime (php & SQL Server stored procedure)

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have the same problem but a little different [from Neil problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638160/error-when-trying-to-insert-date-into-datetime-column) ([Error when trying to insert date into datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638160/error-when-trying-to-insert-date-into-datetime-column)),

Neil want to get now date time so he can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `GETDATE()`.

My question is, how if I have string of date like:

```
$date = '2011-03-29';
```

then I want to insert into SQL Server database using a stored procedure with PHP.

```
 insert into tbl(date) 
 values($date)
```

Can anybody help? Thanks

Just fyi, I have

SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    date datetime
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_insertdate
    (@date datetime)
as
begin
    insert into tbl(date) values(@date)
end
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

  $date = '2011-03-29';  

  include("con.php");  
  $query  = mssql_init("sp_insertdate");
  mssql_bind($query, "@date", &$date, SQLINT4); //sqlint4 for datetime

  mssql_execute($query);

?>
```

The result is 1900-1-1,

I have tried to send the varchar (in php) first then convert to the datetime (in stored procedure) but there is some error.

Really I'm stuck.. any idea for this problem?

I just want to insert string `2011-03-29` into a SQL Server `datetime` column using a stored procedure from PHP. I'm sorry because I can't speak English fluently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer from my friends,

just put 
mssql_bind($query, "@date", &$date, SQLCHAR); //not sqlint4 for datetime but just sqlchar or sqlvarchar

however many thanks to Groovetrain, i can put also
$date='2011-03-29 00:00:00' 
then put

mssql_bind($query, "@date", &$date, SQLCHAR,false,false,19); //19 length of date string

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I've had a problem like this (using mysql), I just had to add the time (midnight) onto the date so that it can recognize it as the `datetime` that it's expecting.  Try this:

```
$date = '2011-03-29';
$date .= ' 00:00:00';
```

Then process the rest as you would.  This works for mysql, maybe sql-server needs it like this too.